# how to display plot images outside of jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

So, this might be an utterly dumb question, but I have just started working with python and it's data science libs, and I would like to see seaborn plots displayed, but I prefer to work with editors I have experience with, like VS Code or PyCharm instead of Jupyter notebook. Of course, when I run the python code, the console does not display the plots as those are images. So how do I get to display and see the plots when not using jupyter?

Comment: What plotting library are you using?  Matplotlib?

Comment: I didn't got your question                                                                                          
if you want  image of that  you can export figures from Ipython notebook

Comment: plt.show()? If you include code, it helps us understand the problem much easier.

Comment: notebook and python shell try to make life easier and they can display result from every line of code. In script you not always want to see all images or text and you have to decide what you want to see using `plt.show()` for plots and `print()` for text.

Comment: i missed plt.show(), you're right

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run an matplotlib example code with python console or ipython console. They will show you a window with your plot. 
Also, you can use Spyder instead of those consoles. It is free, and works well with python libraries for data science. Of course, you can check your plots in Spyder.